# Bug with xelatex filename containing $ followed by other characters

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I am running into an issue when running xelatex from the command line such that when I run this for example I get unexpected behavior for the output pdf name (notice no space between "$" and "T"):

`xelatex Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&\$T\ \(None\).tex`

the output PDF name is (missing "$T"):

`Doc - Test Customer J Doe & (None).pdf`

However, when I run this (notice space between "$" and "T") I get what I expect the output filename would be:

`xelatex Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&\$\ T\ \(None\).tex`

the output PDF name is:

`Doc - Test Customer Bren Teslyt &$ T (None).pdf`

My texlive / xelatex versions are below:

`XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 58.2; using 58.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.7.1; using 2.7.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.9; using 1.3.9
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 1.4.6; using 1.4.6
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.29; using 1.6.29
Compiled with poppler version 0.52.0
Using Mac OS X Core Text and Cocoa frameworks`

Comment: What about `xelatex "Doc - Test Customer J Doe &T (None).pdf"`?

Comment: I confirm that `xelatex 'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).tex'` produces `Doc - Test Customer J Doe & (None).pdf` although the aux and log file do have the `$T`.

Comment: this is a problem with `$T` being interpreted as value of env variable. With `export T='foo'` compilation fails. With `unset T` it then works, but the `$T` has disappeared from pdf filename.

Comment: @Werner sorry, not sure what you mean....Run xelatex on the pdf? Also, the issue is that the "$T" gets stripped when there is no space between them, else everything works fine.

Comment: with `export T='$T'` we get `warning: kpathsea: variable `T' references itself (eventually).`

Comment: @acmisiti: Sorry, that should have been `xelatex "Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).tex"`.

Comment: That is not a XeTeX issue, but a feature of a shell.
On cmd.exe for windows,
`xetex "Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).tex"`
creates
`Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).log`
and
`Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).pdf`.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto there is diverging behaviour of xelatex and pdflatex on mac os. Both report an error if I assign `T` as environment variable. But when `T` is unset (from my bash shell environment), then both work, but the pdf filename produced from xelatex is missing the `$T`, whereas the one from pdflatex is fine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the xelatex run prints `Output written on Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).pdf (1 page).` but the actual filename is `Test Customer J Doe & (None).pdf`. I was tricked into believing at first it did work but then I checked the actual filename via `ls` or my Emacs dired. No such issue on your side?

Comment: @jfbu yes you are right sorry (I deleted my comment) xetex reports one filename but uses another interesting:-( Probably can make a simpler test case without all the spaces.  Oh I guess it is dropping the quote as it hands over to xfvipdfmx...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes I believe too the spaces are irrelevant, it is a matter of `$T` being interpreted as value of environment variable `T`.

Comment: For simpler test filename, just use for example `Test$Ta.tex`. Spaces are irrelevant here, except if there is a space after the dollar sign, as then there is no issue with `$foo` interpretation from shell at some point. Notice that `xelatex` will report having produced `Test$Ta.pdf`, but the actual file produced is `Test.pdf`. (if `Ta` is not set as environment variable)

Comment: @jfbu: Sorry, quoted file names in XeTeX are treated
differently compared with the other cases.

Answer (score 3):

The need to quote or not spaces and special characters on the command line is entirely a feature of the shell (command line processor) that you use.

In bash

```
 xelatex  --no-pdf  Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&\$T\ \(None\).tex
```

will pass the string `Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).tex` to the application and that will work producing the files:

```
$ ls Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&*
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).aux'
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).log'
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).tex'
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).xdv'
```

You can then make the pdf

```
  xdvipdfmx  Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&\$T\ \(None\).xdv
```

resulting in:

```
ls Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&*pdf
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe &$T (None).pdf'
```

So the only issue is that if instead of using `--no-pdf` you allow xetex to internally call `xdvipdfmx` it drops a layer of quoting somewhere and loses the `$`

after

```
xelatex    Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&\$T\ \(None\).tex
```

you get

```
ls Doc\ -\ Test\ Customer\ J\ Doe\ \&*pdf
'Doc - Test Customer J Doe & (None).pdf'
```

with no `$T`

I suppose arguably that's  a xetex bug but as the filename is so weird I don't think having to use xetex and the dvi to pdf conversion separately is such a big problem.

Comment: what about `Test$T.tex` filename? it is less weird and displays the issue also.

Comment: @jfbu well any filename with a `$` in it is pretty weird but yes it os clearly dropping (expanding) the `$` in its internal handover to dvipdfmx, spaces seem to be handled OK, If you do it in two stages as you would with latex followed by dvips it's also OK.

Comment: I may have been a bit harsh on xetex, as I also said regarding pdflatex in a other comment that `pdflatex 'Test$T.tex'` has an issue if environment variable `T` is set. (perhaps its has to be reported to kpathsea library...)

Comment: even in two stages it is not OK if environment variable is set.

Comment: ooh I see same here, that's not good

Comment: texlive is behaving rather curious on windows. $foo is not a variable in the command line but texlive nevertheless expands it.  miktex only expands (as expected) %foo%.

Comment: From kpathsea source:
`/* Do variable and tilde expansion. */`
`name = kpathsea_expand (kpse, const_name);`
Thus const_name is expanded. That is a feature of
kpathsea.
Kpathsea variable in TeX Live is $something in
all platforms. ENV variable %FOO% on windows
is transformed to $FOO in Kpahsea in TeX Live.
On windows case is insensitive.

Comment: I have confirmed that if I change
`name = kpathsea_expand (kpse, const_name);`
to
`name = xstrdup (const_name);`, then
`pdftex 'test$T.tex'`
with the environment variable `T=ttt`
works and creates `test$T.pdf`.
However, probably some good things
in Kpathsea may be lost.